# how to query user in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I quered user in test class using `user id= UserInfo.getUserId()` but i need `contact id` this is possible or not

```
User us = [
    select Id, Contact.accountId, ContactId
    from User
    where Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()
    ];
System.debug('CurrentUser'+us);
UserContact = [
    select Id, AccountID
    from Contact
    where Id=:us.ContactId
];
```

`UserInfo.getUserId()`this id  admin `userid` palese anybody help me.

Comment: If you want to have a user with a contact Id you would have to create a community user and use the runAs function rather than just query from an admin user account.

Answer (score 3):

The ContactID on the User table is only valid for Partner or Customer Community Users.  For internal Salesforce Users, there is no Contact associated with a User record.

Answer (score 0):

Insert Account, Contact and User then you will get Contact Id on User for test Class

Comment: i think  UserInfo.getUserId() getting the admin only

Comment: admin id don't have contact id